No Sound from speaker in my Asus Vivobook 14x pro oled version
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 version on my laptop as a dual boot setup with my Windows 11. Everything works fine, except that there is no sound from the speakers. My alsa shows a very weird setup unlike found online for other similar cases. There seems to be two sound card choices and none of them actually have sound for anything being played.

I am a novice in the linux landscape, so apologies for lack of any information in the question. I am providing outputs of as many commands I could find online related to this issue.
commands of sources and sinks
PS: I have no idea what was my sound card but I vaguely remember it to be realtek.
